# Pair up people from database

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, random

I have to make a button and if that button is clicked it has to pair up every `Name` in my database called that is called "inschrijvingen". But there cannot be double pairs.

So example;

I have 'John' , 'Eric' , 'Chelsea' and 'Peter' in my database ("Inschrijvingen").
Then if the button is clicked i have to get something like:

John has to buy a present for Eric

Eric has to buy a present for Chelsea

Chelsea has to buy a present for Peter

Peter has to buy a present for John

And if for example John logs in, he sees that he has to buy a present for Eric, and what kind of present Eric wants.

I have no idea how to do this but I heard something about Arrays, Sessions and Shuffle aka `Random()`.

- My database name is "Inschrijvingen"
- My session is called 'adminsession'
- The database "Inschrijvingen" has `ID` , `Name` , `password` , `age` , `present`

---

Hope you can help me I have been struggling with this for over 3 days.

Comment: So what your asking is how to get started?  Do you know what code to use to connect to mySQL from PHP? Do you know how to write an SQL query? Do you know how to run an SQL select statement in PHP to get the data you need out of mySQL?  I'm trying to understand where you are up to so we can help you. So if you can use the questions I've just asked as a guide and show what you have for that, or what of those parts you don't have will help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know all those things. The problem is; I don't have a code to show because I don't know how to make an array of the users in my database and that's the first step. After that i have to shuffle them and I also dont know how to do that

Comment: That's the challenge with your question. My question: "Do you know how to run an SQL select statement in PHP to get the data you need out of mySQL?" is the part that puts the data into an array. The best thing to do is Google php mysqli query result to array. The challenge with this site, it's not a discussion forum which is better suited for your type of question where there is back/forth conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have users with id 0 to 20 then:

```
$numbers = range(0, 20);
shuffle($numbers);

foreach ($numbers as $buyer => $recipient) {
    //SET BUYER AND RECIPIENT TO TABLE
}
```

Create join table `presents` with `buyer_id` and `ecipient_id` shuffle like in code above, then when you want to show a person information for whom is buying present just:

```
SELECT name FROM users 
WHERE user_id = (SELECT recipient_id FROM presents WHERE buyer_id = BUYER_ID LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: But it has to check how much ID's i have in my database. And what does recipient mean?

Comment: Recipient is a person to send present. buyer_id and recipient_id are just id of users, names showing roles in relation. you can create array just by selecting id from database: SELECT id FROM users then foreach $users[ID] = ID, and next shuffle to change key, value ID, also you should check if anyone not get himself, if, shuffle again, or just change with next index.

Comment: I really REALLY appreciate your help man, but I still don't get how to grab users from my table and then shuffle them. I also don't know how the person that logs in can see who he has to buy a present for. I think i'm just going to accept my lower grade because this is impossible for me.